# jquery impromptu overriding default width height of impromptu css for one instance

Tags: jquery, impromptu

Does impromptu allow configuring the width/height of the popup message section? I checked the documentation at http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/index.php, but do not see any parameter which allows that.

I am using impromptu version 3.1. I have to display an over-sized prompt, around 900px by 700px (width by height). The default width/height of impromptu is not enough for one of my popups and  so I need to override it for this particular case. Other popups of my site have normal content and so should be of normal size.

In the impromptu css file, there is -

```
div.jqi {width:400px;}
```

So, the width of the message section is fixed.

I just wanted to make sure about this before making any changes myself.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem and am curious what you finally decided to do and how you override div.jqi if that's what you wound up doing.

Answer (score 3):

update css from jquery

`$.prompt(message);`

`$('div.jqi').css('width','530px');`

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem by doing setting up an alternate:

```
div.jqiwide {width:800px}
```

Now, if I do:

```
$.prompt(message,{prefix:jqiwide});
```

I get a popup 800px wide.

If I do:

```
$.prompt(message);
```

I get a popup with the default of 400px.

Not as flexible as I would like, but it is a workaround.

Comment: I made some changes in the impromptu plugin code so that I can pass a dynamic width when I call $.prompt.  Something like - `$.prompt(templateCertificationForm,{promptwidth: 1020, buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false });`

Answer (score 2):

Setting **position: {width: "1000"}** works in later versions of impromptu

Answer (score 0):

change jquery impromptu.css

```
div.jqi{ 
min-width:400px; }
```

set width in html content